# Is there a way to enable debug inspector on Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity)

Tags: unity, 16.04, dconf, gtkinspector

I would like to know if it's possible to enable the debug inspector for the latest version of Ubuntu. I installed `dconf` but there isn't any option to enable the debug inspector and I didn't find information about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You need to install libgtk-3-dev package:
`sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`

2) Then you can enable inspector with:
`gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true`